# How to update subtotal after changing price with observer

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer, bundled-product

I am using an observer to change bundle product price. I have tried events 'checkout_cart_product_add_after' and 'checkout_cart_save_after'. Both events update the product's price but the subtotal remains the same. In my case Price is 50 and the Subtotal is 18.

Observer code (checkout_cart_save_after):

```
public function apply_customprice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
   
    $quote= $observer->getCart()->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $bundleitems) {
        $parentProductId = $bundleitems->getProduct()->getId();
        if($bundleitems->getProduct()->getTypeId() == 'bundle')
        {
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
            $Custom_price= 50;
            $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($bundleitems->getId());
            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $item->setStoreId($storeId);
            $item->setCustomPrice($Custom_price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($Custom_price);
            $item->setProduct($product);
            $item->save();

            //for updating the totals
            $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        }

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but it seems like your question is very similar to [another one that has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7644620/1737136). If so, try to add your observer to the `sales_quote_save_before` event and use this line to force recalculation: `$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();` rather than calling `save()` again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I solved this issue by setting bundle product price to fixed :)

Comment: @Sayali - glad you found a resolution. You should post the details in an answer to your question and mark it as accepted to help others!